# Will newer Siemens AFCI/GFCI circuit breakers handle washing machine loads better than older versions?

Tags: circuit-breaker, washing-machine

We have new LG 4500 washing machine in new townhouse w Siemens breaker panel. LG Washer keeps tripping the breakers (15A Siemens Type QAF2 - CAFCI - w ARC Fault). I hooked up the washer to a 15A Surge Suppressor - worked fine for a few times - maybe under 10 wash loads) - then started tripping again. Guess the surge suppressor got fried???

Anyway, LG Techie recommended replacing the breaker with a [Siemens 15 Amp AFCI/GFCI Q115DF](https://www.homedepot.ca/product/siemens-15-amp-afci-gfci-dual-function-circuit-breaker-plug-on-load-center-style/1001157613) Dual Function Circuit Breaker. LG Techie said the design of the new Siemens breakers installed in my panel is faulty and Siemens has not fixed the faults yet. But my situation with the new townhouse, with warranty and everything, I have to get everything done thru the builders. Still have to hear back from them if they will replace the original breaker with the recommended one. Hopefully it works. Will update posting with developments.

Has anybody had any success with the recommended breaker?

Thx.

Comment: whiteware that has a metal body and water in close proximity to electricity has a tendency to trip GFCIs

Comment: Where in your house is your washing machine located?  If it's in the garage like mine, you might not be required to have AFCI protection at all.  If it's in a laundry room inside your house, then it is required.

Comment: Washer and dryer are on the third floor. Washer has its own line and breaker. Builder just replaced the breaker with the one recommended by LG (builder's electrician even mentioned that their electrical dealer - maybe most dealers, received a note from LG about the recommended breaker). Breaker seems to be able to accept the load now w/o tripping. LG Techie may have been right all along when he said new Siemens breaker was simply too sensitive and trips unnecessarily  Will update if new breaker trips. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The combination of GFCI and AFCI may sound like a good idea, but AFCI’s do not handle motor loads well and motor loads with wave shaping like variable speed on a motor load if just about to be assured of tripping a AFCI protection device. GFCI’s will usually do ok on small motor loads but I have seen them trip when the motor is turned off if there is a problem. In my state the washing machine is a dedicated load and can be a standard breaker if the NEC required device is known to be a problem. I would check your states amendments to the NEC since this is a new washer and hopefully you can swap the breaker out. I do promote whole house surge suppressors as the cheap plug in ones don’t last (if the plug in did work for a while a hole house suppressor will last longer.